# Project Tango native code crash when calling getPoseAtTime()

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, google-project-tango

What I am trying to do is basically getting the position of the device, much like the motion tracking example. I read both the exmaple on Tango's website, and the example Java code. I tried both Mira and Okul version of the SDK, but the crash happens all the time. Unsure about which step I did is wrong.

Full logcat output is post on [github gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dword1511/bbd782040979fdfc122cee2bc4057be4/raw/ca7ad1217bc01774e36411e16500ca918fb55002/tango.log). For a shorter version:

```
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jfieldID was NULL
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]     in call to SetDoubleField
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]     from int com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.GetPoseAtTime(double, int, int, com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPoseData)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] "LTSensorActivity" prio=5 tid=14 Runnable
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x64929dc8 self=0x4b160d68
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | sysTid=14960 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x43f05ec8
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | state=R schedstat=( 2661834 1966000 13 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | stack=0x4b48e000-0x4b492000 stackSize=1040KB
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: art::Thread::DumpStack(std::ostream&) const+87 [0x4165db78] (libart.so)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: ??? [0x415098a6] (libart.so)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+51 [0x4150a254] (libart.so)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: ??? [0x4150d036] (libart.so)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: ??? [0x41510336] (libart.so)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_GetPoseAtTime__DIILcom_google_atap_tangoservice_TangoPoseData_2+57 [0x4b789dfe] (libtango_client_api.so)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.GetPoseAtTime(Native method)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.getPoseAtTime(Tango.java:582)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at info.dword1511.aoasensor.MappingActivity.getLocation(MappingActivity.java:259)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at info.dword1511.aoasensor.MappingActivity.access$000(MappingActivity.java:30)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at info.dword1511.aoasensor.MappingActivity$1.run(MappingActivity.java:48)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] 
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Runtime aborting...
...
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000039b7 (code=-6), thread 14960 (LTSensorAct)
```

Minial code that reproduces the error is post on [github gist](https://gist.github.com/dword1511/cd29f87ce57be1f2bc4fc10c5c215584).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the `poller` is polling the data before Tango is connected? You can only query the data after [this](https://gist.github.com/dword1511/cd29f87ce57be1f2bc4fc10c5c215584#file-tango-java-L106) call is finished, also note that it's in a runnable, so your polling function can potentially run before the connection line is executed.

Comment: I have moved `poller.postDelayed(updateData, DELAY)` (or even `updateData.run()`) right after `tango.connect(config)` but the same problem persists with exactly same output.

Comment: I guess Tango's native code is missing some checking or exception handling?

Comment: Actually I am quite interested in how `com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.throwTangoExceptionIfNeeded()` in Tango support library is implemented, since this does happen a lot when the motion tracking example is starting up. I guess this might be related since I am using Tango API directly? Also is `tango.connect()` synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: tango.connect() is synchronous call. Also, is you system and TangoCore updated?

Comment: I believe it is updated since there is no updates in Google Play or system updates.

Comment: Her I have [a simplified version of the motion tracking example code](https://gist.github.com/dword1511/724e716cf79cbda5e22eaadb73ae98e5), where when I use Tango Support Library it works as intended, while `mTango.getPoseAtTime()` crashes the same way. I have 10 seconds of delay before calling `getPoseAtTime()`

Comment: Same here, but its happening for all examples.